# Disk wipe/erase tools

Tags: windows, hard-disk, wiping

I have a large number of HDDs which I have the intention to sell. So I need to erase them.

I was thinking to buy tool from Blancco or White Canyon. Which tool you advise me to buy? Maybe some other tool?

Comment: 1) i advise you to don't buy anything! -- 2) which kind of disks do you want to erase?

Comment: Which OS, which type(s) of disks.

Comment: I have Win7 and Win10. Disk are HDD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

anyway... in general i would advise to use [DBAN](https://dban.org/) (or it's [unofficial fork dban](https://github.com/NHellFire/dban)) to wipe complete disks:
it would be the universal method because it works from it's own bootable iso, is therefor platform independent, also free (as in speech and beer),... you only need to create a bootable media (CD, DVD, USB, etc.) and start from it.

*an interesting option would be [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/): it offers DBAN and a bunch of other interesting tools on one bootable CD.*

---

for people already using GNU/*nix-systems it may be easier to install and use [`nwipe`](https://github.com/martijnvanbrummelen/nwipe) (it can be considered as DBAN for different hosts) or simple use [`shred`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shred_(Unix)) or [`dd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix_software)#Disk_wipe) from the [GNU Core Utilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities).

---

**BUT** to make it clear, **on SSDs** (or other flash based media) every kind of **"secure deleting" [may be useless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_erasure#Limitations)**!
the worst case would be: you are erasing nearly nothing and just killing your device much quicker than necessary! ...this depends on the hardware (controller) of the device! - in this case your best chance would be a "built in firmware" or special software from the manufacturer.