# Is there an alternative for active tools for formatting and creating partition?

Tags: security, information-management, usb, hard-disk

I'm trying to format my usb pendrive with one of those low level options like Gutmann, DoD or filling with zeros to wipe all data.

I used Active DVD tools on Windows XP SP3 for years, but I always had the problem that happened after formating my pendrives they were not recognized by the OS and asked me to format again using Windows tool, which I did for FAT32 and hopefully they could be used again.

However a while ago I tried to do the same for an old pendrive on Windows 7 but the software freezed and rendered the drive unusable. Needless to mention that such drive was working just fine, but it seemed the software did satured the chip or overused during the process as it felt hot on contact after the attempt.

After such experience I'm looking for other options which could be safer, cover all the basics and be less consuming of resources i.e RAM, CPU and so on. Therefore, is there any recommendation on an utility which can do low level format and then format exFat, FAT32 or NTFS and creating a partition preferably open source or any at a reasonable cost and good reputation?

On my own I did a quick search and it gave me Eraser (which I'm not sure if it is a format utility) and Rufus which some user has complained about making unusable some of his pendrives. But since I have no experience with these can somebody recommend other tools? If possible one which do offers some graphic user interfase or an easy to use or to understand command line.

The program I'm looking for must be compatible with x86 technology and 32-bit as this is the one I'm using.

As long it works on 32-bit Windows from 7 to onwards is fine. It does not matter if its free. Although open source or free could be preferred. Regarding budget the cost should be reasonable, maybe over 200 usd is too much.

Comment: regarding "secure erasing" you may also have a look at this answer from a while ago: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/39416/9157

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let me start by trying to clarify something. Windows talks about formatting, but is actually mixing several things.

On floppies and old hard drives, formatting was needed to establish a format on the media. Did you format a floppy as 720kB or 1440kB? It often also used to test for bad blocks, which could then be recorded (in the file system) in order to avoid storing data on them. These days all common media (sd cards, usb flash, ssd, hdd) have reserved sectors for replacing bad blocks, so the operating system or software doesn't need to know about bad blocks.

Then there's creating a file system. mkfs in unix. But windows combines all of these and calls it formatting.

Gutmann and DoD methods should more accurately be called wiping or securely erasing. The reason why you had to format as FAT (i.e. create a FAT-filesystem) is because wiping doesn't create a file system. That's completely natural. They scramble the storage media on a lower level, removing the file system structure.

So I suggest you use some software to wipe and something else to partition and create file systems. Formatting in the strictest sense in no longer required.

For wiping you could use SATA Secure Erase or something that writes zeros, DoD or Gutmann patterns. I've used Darik's Boot And Nuke, or DBAN.

For partitioning and file system creating, you can use Windows Disk Management or Parted Magic. In Windows it can be found Win+X -> Disk Management.

[Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) contains DBAN, Parted Magic and many more similar utilities.

Comment: Alright I understood about the FAT you mentioned, but my problem arises after wiping data it just happened that the resulting drive was unrecognizable by any Partition software so I suspect that there is some risk of damaging the device when wiping the information on low level, if that is the case does that mean the device is damaged and unrecoverable?

Comment: The old pendrive might have just died. Or some cheap and bad ones can't handle anything other than FAT on the drive. So maybe the firmware crashed because of the wipe?

Comment: It could be that but I did wiped all data before in other computer using the same system and I could make a partition using windows own format tool. But when I tried to do the same in Windows 7 it didn't worked. But I noticed that the pendrive got very hot during the process of wiping. Thus I ask about if there is some risk when wiping information. DBAN clearly mentions that it discloses any responsibility from damaging devices and that there is no possibility that this can happen. But I'd rather not to be toying around with this until I'm certain I wont damage a brand new device.

Comment: anyway it is not recommended to "secure erase" flash based media (like usual usb-pendrives): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_erasure#Limitations -- bottom line: the data may still be recoverable and you'll only shorten the life of your pendrive.

Comment: Yes, Secure Erase would be better, but USB flash devices usually don't support it. The best solution to securely wiping sensitive data is to _always_ store it encrypted and then destroy the encryption key when you want to wipe.

Comment: @ptman If USB flash devices don't support it why so many programs out there make it seem the contrary. Or could it be that I am not understand it right?. How about other media such as SD and microSD would it be okay to use DBAN on them without any risk?. Physically speaking what is happening when the process of "data wiping" is taking place? Why does it shortens the life of the device?. Is it an electrical stress or something?. Does overheating during the process can damage the device as I suspect it happened to my pendrive?.

Comment: I'm talking about [ATA Secure Erase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA#HDD_passwords_and_security)

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: 1) every cell of [flash-storages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory) (SSD, USB-pendrive, SD-cards, etc.) has a limited number of changing their state. -- 2) controller of flash-storages manage to use all cells somehow equal often ([Wear leveling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling)) to maximize the device-lifetime. -- 3) this, spare cells, caching and other techniques of flash-storages makes it unlikely to really completely wipe a flash-storage. -- 4) electrical stress and heat shouldn't be a problem... at least for storages from reasonable manufacturers.

Comment: my guess, why there are wipe-programs out there which suggest easy wiping of flash-storages is, that their producers are rather interested in selling/spreading their product, than in educating their customers. :-( **||** as mentioned in my linked answer: your best chance to really wipe data from a flash-storage would be a "built in firmware" or special software from the manufacturer, which is in most cases just available for SSDs, if anything.

Comment: once again: the best way to secure your data whether on HDDs, SSDs or any other storage is to use [FDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption#Full_disk_encryption). - and additional this also protects your existing data in case of loosing the device/storage.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy How many times can those flash storage change their states?. I mean in average, is there any statistics regarding major brands about this?. I've also read some articles which do seem to say that manufacturers produce software for formatting their own drives and as you mentioned it is available for SSD. In the end it looks that I'll give it DBAN a try.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell: well... there is no rule of thumb for manufacturers, brands or product-lines because it depends on so many different factors (design & complexity of Wear leveling, MLC/SLC/TLC, NAND/NOR, semiconductor-design, etc.), but you can find numbers from 3.000 to 100.000 theoretical cycles. - it may be that you can find some details about your device in its manual. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

ImDisk Tool kit

https://sourceforge.net/projects/imdisk-toolkit/

This tool will let you mount image files of hard drive, cd-rom or floppy, and create one or several ramdisks with various parameters.

This all-in-one package includes the ImDisk Virtual Disk Driver (2.0.9), the DiscUtils library that extends the number of supported image file formats, and adds several GUIs and features.

64-bit:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/imdisk-toolkit/files/20170706/ImDiskTk-x64.exe

32-bit:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/imdisk-toolkit/files/20170706/ImDiskTk.exe

Features

- Ramdisk with optional dynamic memory management
- Image file mounting, many formats supported

Comment: Wait a sec. Does this software you mention allows create partition and wiping data from a drive with security options and all that?. It must be compatible with Windows 7 as well I'm using this.